# arduino/raspberry based current and voltage monitoring using Rogowski coil

Tags: arduino, voltage, current

I am working on a project to build a current and voltage monitoring device (3 phase) using rogowski coils as sensors. It seems that usually CT are used with raspberry or arduino so I would like to have your opinions:
using Rogowski coils, what kind of ADC/integrator (or integrating ADC) do I need (are there different types)? 
Concerning ADC: can I make/program one myself or is it best to buy one?
Thanks in advance! 
cheers

Comment: Most (all?) microcontrollers you buy have ADCs in built, the one on the arduino has an ADC. The wikipedia page on ADCs has an overview of the major types.

Comment: Please justify the use of R-coils as opposed to CTs.

Comment: Andy aka: I need the R-coils to measure current in buildings, so I need to be able to just clip them around the phases without removing the cables..

Comment: So, why not use a CT with that clip-on clip-off facility. They are made and available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the R-coils to measure current in buildings, so I need to be
>   able to just clip them around the phases without removing the cables

So, why not use a CT with that clip-on clip-off facility. They are made and [available](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/products/8199779/?grossPrice=Y&cm_mmc=UK-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-PLA_UK_EN_Automation_And_Control_Gear-_-Panel_Meters_And_Components%7CCurrent_Transformers-_-PRODUCT+GROUP&matchtype=&gclid=Cj0KCQiAh_DTBRCTARIsABlT9Ma6z9xbgak7BENjzrRjo4tJBJCgrPMGYAAgOwHFjYVgJLiW1S_cgq4aAgFmEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds): -

[image]

[image]

> I would like to have your opinions: using Rogowski coils, what kind of
>   ADC/integrator (or integrating ADC) do I need (are there different
>   types)?

I think that given a regular CT should be considered, this question is now irrelevant. There are plenty of ADCs but, if you really want to use a R-coil then you will need a linear integrating circuit like this: -

[image]

Choose R1 to be bigger than 330 kohm to ensure that it doesn't have an effect at 50 Hz - possibly 3.3 Mohm. Or make C1 something like 100 nF.

Comment: Wow ok thank you. I got a bit confused now.. I need to be able to measure current between (if possible 0- at least 200A), in probably small places/little distance between the cables (i imagine).That's why I thought the Rogowski coil would be best as the CT have large diameters for larger currents, if i get  that right.
and sorry for this question but I am new to these topics:
is the integrating circuit part of the ADC?

Comment: ADCs don’t normally incorporate an integrator. I think CT is your best approach still.

Comment: There is a "currency" for "thanks" (to save you having to be so polite). That currency is aslo very acceptable. If you ask a question and you get answers and you are satisfied with at least one answer then you can formally accept that answer. So, I'd wait a day to see if other better answers turn up and choose one to formally accept.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an IC such as ADE7759 which is a digital integrator with high accuracy no need for analog circuit. You can check also this paper why R-Coils are more common the last 5 years for high current measurments.

https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/current-sensing-for-energy-metering.html